# I need solution keeping image and text both at a center in same form

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Image and text should be in center. Text goes to the center but image falls on the top of text. I want text and image in same way but only at the center. Thanks in advance

[image: .]

**Below is my code:**

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default  navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->


    <div class='col-md-12-fluid' style="
     
        padding-bottom: 2px;
        background-color:#7E8F7C;
       
        ">
      <div class "row" style="background-color:red !important">
        <div class='col-md-8-fluid'>
          <!--recently search was here-->
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"></a>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-4-fluid' style="background-color:#3B3738; height:25px;">
          <h3>Nepal Safety</h3>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="row">
        <div class='col-md-8-fluid'>
          <!--recently search was here-->
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
            <img src="images/iccn.png" height="50px" width="100px">
          </a>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class='col-md-4-fluid'>
          <h3>Nepal Safety</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='clearfix'></div>
    <div class="navbar-header">
```

Comment: Crusader, create [jsfiddle-example](https://jsfiddle.net/) with issue behavior

Answer (score 2):

Here it is:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default  navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->


    <div class='col-md-12-fluid' style="padding-bottom: 2px; background-color:#7E8F7C; min-height: 500px;">
      <div class="row" style="background-color:red !important">
        <div class='col-md-8-fluid'>
          <!--recently search was here-->
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"></a>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-4-fluid' style="background-color:#3B3738; height:25px;">
          <h3>Nepal Safety</h3>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="row" style="clear: both">
        <div class='col-md-8-fluid' style="width: 500px; margin: 0 auto; background: blue">
          <!--recently search was here-->
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html" style="float: left">
            <img src="images/iccn.png" height="50px" width="100px">
          </a>
          
          <h3>Nepal Safety</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='clearfix'></div>
    <div class="navbar-header">
```

Comment: image must appear on left of text and text should be just right of the image in center. Here image appears on top which is already done. #ThankYou

Comment: I've edited the code, you just have to set the width of your container, `margin: 0 auto;` will center the block. By the way, the image and title have to be in the same div

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default  navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->


    <div class='col-md-12-fluid' style="

        padding-bottom: 2px;
        background-color:#7E8F7C;

        ">
      <div class="row" style="background-color:red !important">
        <div class='col-md-8-fluid'>
          <!--recently search was here-->
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"></a>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-4-fluid' style="background-color:#3B3738; height:25px;">
          <h3>Nepal Safety</h3>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="row">
        <div class='col-md-6'>
          <!--recently search was here-->
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html" style="float:right;">
            <img src="images/iccn.png" height="50px" width="100px">
          </a>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class='col-md-6'>
          <h3>Nepal Safety</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='clearfix'></div>
    <div class="navbar-header">
```

I changed the columns to be 6 and 6, making them each half the width of the screen. I removed "fluid" from the column classes (since you've got the encompassing div set to fluid, you don't need any of its children fluid). Finally, I floated the image right so it'll sit beside the header.

Tell me if that's what you were looking for!